# Matching Facebook event URLs with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to match URLs for Facebook Events which look like this:

> https://www.facebook.com/events/1880811115562133/

I want https and the trailing slash to be optional. The event ID length should be between 10 and 20.

This is my progress so far:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?facebook.com\/events\/^[0-9]{10,20}$
```

Comment: Improved the grammar and formatting. You may also want to update the question to show the results of the regex and what it is matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:https?\:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/events\/\d{10,20}\/?$
```

Comment: you've saved me a lot of time 

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`\w{4,5}:\/\/\w{3}\.\w{8}\.\w{3}\/\w{6}\/\d{10,20}\/?`
     https:// or http:// is between 4 and 5 
ID length  10 and 20 
 and slash /?  is optional.

Try to use this helpfull tool to check if You follow in right way 
 this is Yours example https://regex101.com/r/vmNdXY/1